# Remove the brackets and apostrophes from print output

Tags: printing

I would like to remove the [' and the '] from the printed output. My code looks like this.

```
text = input("Text: ")
words = text.split()


bigrams = {}
for i in range(len(words) - 1):
  current_word = words[i]
  next_word = words[i+1]
  bigrams[current_word] = []
  bigrams[current_word].append(next_word)


for k, v in bigrams.items():
    print(k,v)
```

The current output...

```
Text: This is a sentence for the bigrams
This ['is']
is ['a']
a ['sentence']
sentence ['for']
for ['the']
the ['bigrams']
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). You don't seem to have mentioned what language you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently using the default behaviour in python for printing lists. If you want something prettier, you could go for a for loop:

```py
for k, v in bigrams.items():
    out = f"{k}:"
    for elem in v:
        out += f" {elem},"
    out = out[:-1] # remove last ','
    print(out)
```

Though I believe that in your current implementation, your lists will always have exactly 1 element, as you initialize them repeatedly in `bigrams[current_word] = []` and then append one element. If this is intended, than you can print with:

```py
for k, v in bigrams.items():
    print(f"{k}, {v[0]}")
```